# Multiple slide in jQuery panels for contact forms

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am very new to this, I can't get the below to function correctly. I need each of the panels to slide in when a user clicks on the corresponding button. Also if there is already a panel open it needs to slide out when the user clicks on a new location, and the new location's panel needs to slide in. When I click "Perth" button the panel just disappears. I think I made a total mess of it. Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers

http://jsfiddle.net/mattej/n7Yhe/

**Final Revision**

http://jsfiddle.net/mattej/n7Yhe/5/

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="w3c" style="">
    <div id="sydney"> <a href="#sydney">Sydney</a>

    </div>
    <div id="melbourne"> <a href="#melbourne">Melbourne</a>

    </div>
    <div id="brisbane"> <a href="#brisbane">Brisbane</a>

    </div>
    <div id="adelaide"> <a href="#adelaide">Adelaide</a>

    </div>
    <div id="darwin"> <a href="#darwin">Darwin</a>

    </div>
    <div id="hobart"> <a href="#hobart">Hobart</a>

    </div>
    <div id="perth"> <a href="#perth">Perth</a>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="w3c1">
    <input type="hidden" name="p" id="s" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="p" id="m" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="p" id="b" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="p" id="a" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="p" id="d" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="p" id="h" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="p" id="p" value="0">
    <div id="nsydney" style="display:block;">
        <div id='crmWebToEntityForm' align='center' style="display:block;"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="nmelbourne" style="display:block;">
        <div id='crmWebToEntityForm' align='center' style="display:block;"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="nbrisbane" style="display:block;">
        <div id='crmWebToEntityForm' align='center' style="display:block;"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="nadelaide" style="display:block;">
        <div id='crmWebToEntityForm' align='center' style="display:block;"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="ndarwin" style="display:block;">
        <div id='crmWebToEntityForm' align='center' style="display:block;"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="nhobart" style="display:block;">
        <div id='crmWebToEntityForm' align='center' style="display:block;"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="nperth" style="display:block;">
        <div id='crmWebToEntityForm' align='center' style="display:block;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

Please see jfiddle

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#crmWebToEntityForm").hide();
$("#nsydney").hide();
$("#nmelbourne").hide();
$("#nperth").hide();
$("#nbrisbane").hide();
$("#nadelaide").hide();
$("#ndarwin").hide();
$("#nhobart").hide();
$("#sydney").click(function () {

    $("#nsydney").show('slow');
    $("#nmelbourne").hide();
    $("#nperth").hide();
    $("#nbrisbane").hide();
    $("#nadelaide").hide();
    $("#ndarwin").hide();
    $("#nhobart").hide();
    $("#crmWebToEntityForm").show('slow');
    var p = $('#s').val();
    if (p == 0) {
        $('#p').val(1);

    } else {
        $('#p').val(0);
        $("#nmelbourne").hide();
        $("#ndarwin").hide();
        $("#nbrisbane").hide();
        $("#nhobart").hide();
        $("#nadelaide").hide();
        $("#nperth").hide();
        $("#nsydney").hide();
        $(".w3c").animate({
            right: '0px'
        }, "fast");
    }
    //$( ".w3c" ).toggle(function() {
    //$('.w3c').css("right", "300px");
    //  }, function() {
    //  $('.w3c').css("right", "165px");
    //  });
    //$('.w3c').animate({left: '1025px'});
    //$('.w3c').css("marginRight", "265px");
    //jQuery('#nsydney').animate({left: '1025px'}, "fast");
    //$("#nsydney").animate("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1200);
    //$('#nsydney').animate({ direction: "left" }, 10);
    //$("#nsydney").toggle({ direction: "left" }, 8000);
});
$("#melbourne").click(function () {
    $("#nsydney").hide();
    $("#nmelbourne").show('slow');
    $("#nperth").hide();
    $("#nbrisbane").hide();
    $("#nadelaide").hide();
    $("#ndarwin").hide();
    $("#nhobart").hide();
    var p = $('#m').val();
    if (p == 0) {
        $('#p').val(1);

    } else {
        $('#p').val(0);
        $("#nsydney").hide();
        $("#nmelbourne").hide();
        $("#ndarwin").hide();
        $("#nbrisbane").hide();
        $("#nhobart").hide();
        $("#nadelaide").hide();
        $("#nperth").hide();
        $(".w3c").animate({
            right: '0px'
        }, "fast");
    }
    //$('.w3c').css("marginRight", "265px");
    // $("#nmelbourne").animate({ left: '1025px' }, "fast");
});
$("#perth").click(function () {
    $("#nsydney").hide();
    $("#nmelbourne").hide();
    $("#nperth").show('slow');
    $("#nbrisbane").hide();
    $("#nadelaide").hide();
    $("#ndarwin").hide();
    $("#nhobart").hide();
    var p = $('#p').val();
    if (p == 0) {
        $('#p').val(1);

    } else {
        $('#p').val(0);
        $("#nsydney").hide();
        $("#nmelbourne").hide();
        $("#ndarwin").hide();
        $("#nbrisbane").hide();
        $("#nhobart").hide();
        $("#nadelaide").hide();
        $("#nperth").hide();
        $(".w3c").animate({
            right: '0px'
        }, "fast");
    }
    //$('.w3c').css("marginRight", "265px");
    // $("#nperth").animate( { left: '1025px' }, "fast");
});
$("#brisbane").click(function () {
    $("#nsydney").hide();
    $("#nmelbourne").hide();
    $("#nperth").hide();
    $("#nadelaide").hide();
    $("#ndarwin").hide();
    $("#nhobart").hide();
    $("#nbrisbane").show('slow');
    var p = $('#b').val();
    if (p == 0) {
        $('#p').val(1);

    } else {
        $('#p').val(0);
        $("#nsydney").hide();
        $("#nmelbourne").hide();
        $("#nperth").hide();
        $("#ndarwin").hide();
        $("#nhobart").hide();
        $("#nadelaide").hide();
        $("#nbrisbane").hide();
        $(".w3c").animate({
            right: '0px'
        }, "fast");
    }
    //$('.w3c').css("marginRight", "265px");
    // $("#nbrisbane").animate( { left: '1025px'}, "fast");
});
$("#adelaide").click(function () {
    $("#nsydney").hide();
    $("#nmelbourne").hide();
    $("#nperth").hide();
    $("#nbrisbane").hide();
    $("#ndarwin").hide();
    $("#nhobart").hide();
    $("#nadelaide").show('slow');
    var p = $('#a').val();
    if (p == 0) {
        $('#p').val(1);

    } else {
        $('#p').val(0);
        $("#nsydney").hide();
        $("#nmelbourne").hide();
        $("#nperth").hide();
        $("#nbrisbane").hide();
        $("#ndarwin").hide();
        $("#nhobart").hide();
        $("#nadelaide").hide();
        $(".w3c").animate({
            right: '0px'
        }, "fast");
    }
    //$('.w3c').css("marginRight", "265px");
    //$("#nadelaide").animate({ left: '1025px' }, "fast");
});
$("#darwin").click(function () {
    $("#nsydney").hide();
    $("#nmelbourne").hide();
    $("#nperth").hide();
    $("#nbrisbane").hide();
    $("#nadelaide").hide();
    $("#ndarwin").show('slow');
    $("#nhobart").hide();
    var p = $('#d').val();
    if (p == 0) {
        $('#p').val(1);

    } else {
        $('#p').val(0);
        $("#nsydney").hide();
        $("#nmelbourne").hide();
        $("#nperth").hide();
        $("#nbrisbane").hide();
        $("#nadelaide").hide();
        $("#ndarwin").hide();
        $("#nhobart").hide();
        $(".w3c").animate({
            right: '0px'
        }, "fast");
    }
    //$('.w3c').css("marginRight", "265px");
    //$("#ndarwin").animate( { left: '1025px' }, "fast");
});
$("#hobart").click(function () {
    $("#nsydney").hide();
    $("#nmelbourne").hide();
    $("#nperth").hide();
    $("#nbrisbane").hide();
    $("#nadelaide").hide();
    $("#ndarwin").hide();
    $("#nhobart").show('slow');
    var p = $('#h').val();
    if (p == 0) {
        $('#p').val(1);

    } else {
        $('#p').val(0);
        $("#nsydney").hide();
        $("#nmelbourne").hide();
        $("#nperth").hide();
        $("#nbrisbane").hide();
        $("#nadelaide").hide();
        $("#ndarwin").hide();
        $("#nhobart").hide();
        $(".w3c").animate({
            right: '0px'
        }, "fast");
    }
    //$('.w3c').css("marginRight", "265px");
    //$("#nhobart").animate( { left: '1025px' }, "fast");
});
```

});

Comment: Just a hint: you can't have multiple elements with the same id (like `id="crmWebToEntityForm"`). Use a class instead.

Comment: Okay... you need to stop referencing every single thing by id and apply a class to all of them so you can just do $('.my-class').hide(). That will clean up your code so we can start looking at other things.

Comment: You also want to use `data-location` attributes to do what you need with all of those locations. Instead of repeating the same lines of code but tweaked a little, *abstract out a function or two*. You could bind one click function to a *class* and then in that function, call `$(this).data('location')` to get that piece of information and work from there.

Comment: Ok great, thanks guys. I'll keep working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By abstracting your functions out and using classes instead of ids, you can greatly shorten your code and make it easier to see what's going on:

### HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="w3c" style="">
        <div>
            <a href="#sydney" data-location="sydney">Sydney</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#melbourne" data-location="melbourne">Melbourne</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#brisbane" data-location="brisbane">Brisbane</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#adelaide" data-location="adelaide">Adelaide</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#darwin" data-location="darwin">Darwin</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#hobart" data-location="hobart">Hobart</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#perth" data-location="perth">Perth</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="formContainer">
        <div data-location="sydney" class='crmWebToEntityForm'></div>
        <div data-location="melbourne" class='crmWebToEntityForm'></div>
        <div data-location="brisbane" class='crmWebToEntityForm'></div>
        <div data-location="adelaide" class='crmWebToEntityForm'></div>
        <div data-location="darwin" class='crmWebToEntityForm'></div>
        <div data-location="hobart" class='crmWebToEntityForm'></div>
        <div data-location="perth" class='crmWebToEntityForm'></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

### Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.w3c a').click(function() {
        var location = $(this).data('location');
        var formSelector = '.crmWebToEntityForm[data-location="' + location + '"]';
        console.log(formSelector);
        var targetForm = $(formSelector);
        var formWasAlreadyVisible = targetForm.is(':visible');

        $('.w3c a').removeClass('selected');
        $(".crmWebToEntityForm:visible").hide();

        if (formWasAlreadyVisible) {
            return;   
        }

        $(this).addClass('selected');
        targetForm.show();
    });
});
```

### CSS

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 20px;
}
.w3c {
    min-height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    width: 40%;
    float:left;
}
.w3c > div {
    display: inline;
}
.w3c > div > a {
    margin-left: -1px;
    position: relative;
    left: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    background: #dadada;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    font-size:14px;
}
.w3c > div:not(:target) > a {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white, #eee);
}
.w3c > div > a.selected {
    background: white;
}
.w3c > div > div {
    background: white;
    z-index: -2;
    padding:0px;
    border: 0px solid #ccc;
    float:right;
    right:0px;
    width:300px;
}
.w3c > div:not(:target) > div {
    position: absolute
}
.w3c > div:target > div {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
.formContainer {
    float: right;
    min-height: 250px;
    /*position: relative;*/
    width: 40%;
}
.formContainer > div > a {
    margin-left: -1px;
    position: relative;
    left: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    background: #dadada;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    font-size:14px;
}
.crmWebToEntityForm {
    background: white;
    z-index: -2;
    padding:0px;
    border: 0px solid #ccc;
    float:right;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
    background-color: #606060 !important;
    box-shadow: -5px 0 5px rgba(174, 174, 174, 0.8);
    width: 320px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n7Yhe/3/

Comment: Wow that is much simpler. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks again for all your help, I just added the animation to get it sliding the way I want. Here is the final revision http://jsfiddle.net/mattej/n7Yhe/4/